# TStringList.IndexOf() causes thread to crash

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I've been writing unit to search for files that end with specified extensions and with ability to skip searching through specified directories. This data is contained in `FExtensions` and `FIgnorePaths` `TStringList` objects, respectively.

However, approximately 1 out of 10 runs, thread crashes with following exception:

[image: thread crash exception]

After debugging a bit, I isolated this line in search thread as a crash cause:

```
if FExtensions.IndexOf(ExtractFileExt(search_rec.Name)) <> -1 then
```

I've tried to do `Assigned(FExtensions)` check before I call `IndexOf()`, but that didn't eliminated the crash. If I comment this line, thread stress test works fine (creating/destroying it with 100ms intervals). I know that `TStringList` isn't thread safe, but I do not access `FExtensions` nor any other `TStringList` in thread anywhere out of it's scope, so concurrent access shouldn't be crash cause.

Here is the file search thread unit:

```
unit uFileSearchThread;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TFileSearchThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FExternalMessageHandler: HWND;
    FMsg_FSTDone           : Cardinal;

    FPath                  : String;
    FIgnorePaths           : TStringList;
    FExtensions            : TStringList;
    FFiles                 : TStringList;

    function IsIgnoreDir(const ADir: String; out AKeepIgnoreCheck: Boolean): Boolean;

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

  public
    constructor Create(const APath: String; const AIgnorePaths: TStringList; const AAllowedExtensions: TStringList; const AExternalMessageHandler: HWND; const AMsg_FSTDone: Cardinal);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Path : String read FPath;
    property Files: TStringList read FFiles;

  end;

  TFileSearchThreads = TObjectList<TFileSearchThread>;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.StrUtils;


constructor TFileSearchThread.Create(const APath: String; const AIgnorePaths: TStringList; const AAllowedExtensions: TStringList; const AExternalMessageHandler: HWND; const AMsg_FSTDone: Cardinal);
begin
  inherited Create(TRUE);

  FExternalMessageHandler := AExternalMessageHandler;
  FMsg_FSTDone := AMsg_FSTDone;

  FPath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(APath);

  FIgnorePaths := TStringList.Create;
  FIgnorePaths.Assign(AIgnorePaths);

  FExtensions := TStringList.Create;
  FExtensions.Assign(AAllowedExtensions);

  FFiles := TStringList.Create;

  WriteLn(FPath, ' file search thread created.');
 end;

destructor TFileSearchThread.Destroy;
begin
  FExtensions.Free;
  FIgnorePaths.Free;

  WriteLn(FPath, ' file search thread destroyed.');

  inherited;
end;

function TFileSearchThread.IsIgnoreDir(const ADir: String; out AKeepIgnoreCheck: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  C1: Integer;
begin
  AKeepIgnoreCheck := FALSE;
  if not Assigned(FIgnorePaths) then
    Exit(FALSE);

  for C1 := 0 to FIgnorePaths.Count - 1 do
    if AnsiStartsText(FIgnorePaths[C1], ADir) then
      Exit(TRUE)
    else
      if not AKeepIgnoreCheck then
        AKeepIgnoreCheck := AnsiStartsText(ADir, FIgnorePaths[C1]);

  Exit(FALSE);
end;

procedure TFileSearchThread.Execute;
var
  search_rec      : TSearchRec;
  dirs            : TStringList;
  dirs_nocheck    : TStringList;
  dir             : String;
  ignore_check    : Boolean;
  ignore_check_tmp: Boolean;
  newdir          : String;
begin
  dirs := TStringList.Create;
  try
    dirs_nocheck := TStringList.Create;
    try
      dirs.Add(FPath);

      while (not Terminated) and
            ((dirs.Count > 0) or (dirs_nocheck.Count > 0)) do
      begin
        ignore_check := dirs.Count > 0;
        if ignore_check then
        begin
          dir := dirs[0];
          dirs.Delete(0);
        end
        else
        begin
          dir := dirs_nocheck[0];
          dirs_nocheck.Delete(0);
        end;

        if (not ignore_check) or
           (not IsIgnoreDir(LowerCase(dir), ignore_check)) then
          if FindFirst(dir + '*', faAnyFile, search_rec) = 0 then
          try
            repeat
              if (search_rec.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then
              begin
                if FExtensions.IndexOf(ExtractFileExt(search_rec.Name)) <> -1 then // crashes here
                  FFiles.Add(dir + search_rec.Name);
              end
              else
                if (search_rec.Name <> '.') and (search_rec.Name <> '..') then
                begin
                  newdir := dir + search_rec.Name + '\';
                  if not ignore_check then
                    dirs_nocheck.Add(newdir)
                  else
                    if not IsIgnoreDir(LowerCase(newdir), ignore_check_tmp) then
                      if ignore_check_tmp then
                        dirs.Add(newdir)
                      else
                        dirs_nocheck.Add(newdir);
                end;
            until (Terminated) or (FindNext(search_rec) <> 0);
          finally
            FindClose(search_rec);
          end;
      end;
    finally
      dirs_nocheck.Free;
    end;
  finally
    dirs.Free;
  end;

  PostMessage(FExternalMessageHandler, FMsg_FSTDone, NativeUInt(pointer(self)), 0);
end;

end.
```

<sub>(I know that I don't free FFiles in destructor, but that is because I want to avoid data duplication, so I pass it after thread destruction to another object that keeps using it)</sub>

And procedure that creates the thread:

```
procedure CreateFileSearchThread(const APath: String);
const
  {$I ignore_dirs.inc}
  {$I allowed_extensions.inc}
var
  ignore_dirs_list, allowed_exts_list: TStringList;
  file_search_thread                 : TFileSearchThread;
  C1                                 : Integer;
begin
  ignore_dirs_list := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ignore_dirs_list.Sorted := TRUE;
    ignore_dirs_list.CaseSensitive := FALSE;
    ignore_dirs_list.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

    for C1 := Low(IGNORE_DIRS) to High(IGNORE_DIRS) do
      ignore_dirs_list.Add(LowerCase(ExpandEnvStrings(IGNORE_DIRS[C1])));

    allowed_exts_list := TStringList.Create;
    try
      allowed_exts_list.Sorted := TRUE;
      allowed_exts_list.CaseSensitive := FALSE;
      allowed_exts_list.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

      for C1 := Low(ALLOWED_EXTS) to High(ALLOWED_EXTS) do
        allowed_exts_list.Add('.' + ALLOWED_EXTS[C1]);

      file_search_thread := TFileSearchThread.Create(APath, ignore_dirs_list, allowed_exts_list, FMessageHandler, FMsg_FSTDone);
      FFileSearchThreads.Add(file_search_thread);
      file_search_thread.Start;
    finally
      allowed_exts_list.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ignore_dirs_list.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I destroy thread simply by calling `FFileSearchThreads.Free`, which then should free it's objects, since `OwnObjects` is set to `TRUE`. `FFileSearchThreads` is of `TObjectList<TFileSearchThread>` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I destroy thread simply by calling FFileSearchThreads.Free, 
>   which then should free it's objects, since OwnObjects is 
>   set to TRUE. FFileSearchThreads is of TObjectList 
>   type.

Wait a moment. You tell your threads to **Terminate()** before and **WaitFor()** them to complete, do you? If not, then you really should do that!

A thread does not only consist of the data stored in the TThread instance. It allocates a bunch of system resources associated to a operating system thread object, which represents a single flow/context of execution. These resources must be deallocated properly and the execution needs to be stopped, before you can Free() the Delphi object around the internal OS object.

It could be worth taking `FreeOnTerminate := TRUE` into consideration, essentially letting the Threads do their cleanup work alone. You are still responsible for initiating this process, usually by setting a shared global flag or `TEvent` instance or something like that. This way you are able to decouple the things and get rid of the thread list. Both methods have their pro's and con's.

Comment: I believe `TThread.Destroy()` already does this? (`Terminate()` then `WaitFor()`). Check the `System.Classes.TThread.Destroy()` destructor code.

Comment: Ok, so I've just tried .Terminate() and .WaitFor() instead only freeing the objectlist and it works! But what is the purpose of the identical code that is in `.Destroy()` of the `TThread`, and why it doesn't work that way?

Comment: You first free your data structures, then call `inherited Destroy`. Besides, from my feeling a DTOR is not the correct place to wait for a Thread to terminate, and IMHO the VCL code is just there to avoid the obvious. But that's my personal optinion.

Comment: This makes no sense. Look at the destructor of `TThread`. It calls `Terminate` and then `WaitFor`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Isn't the code execution flow like this: `TFileSearchThread.Destroy()` > which frees `FExtensions/FIgnorePaths` then calls `inherited Destroy()`, which is actually `TThread.Destroy()`, and then it does the `Terminate()/WaitFor()` combo. So this way I'm freeing objects before `Terminate/WaitFor`, and thats why it's crashing? Putting `inherited;` before `FExtensions.Free()` fixes the crash too, so I believe it makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, I get it now. That does explain it. I'd just reached the same conclusion myself. But the answer as written does not explain the problem. I'd like to see a real answer that explains this. If I were you I would move all the classes to be local variables of `Execute`. Pass the information to them by making copies of the lists of strings into dynamic arrays in the CTOR.

Comment: "Pass the information to them by making copies of the lists of strings into dynamic arrays in the CTOR" - so you're saying to copy the `TStringList` contents into dynamic arrays in CTOR, then fill local `TStringLists` in `.Execute()` with data from those dynamic arrays. I'm curious how would that help?

Comment: It would make it impossible for you to access objects after they were destroyed. Making things local always helps avoid such pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here is what is going on:

1. The `Execute` method is using the `FIgnorePaths` and `FExtensions` objects.
2. The destructor destroys those objects whilst `Execute` is still in flight.
3. Then `Execute` accesses these objects after they have been freed. BOOM!

Look at the destructor of your thread:

```
destructor TFileSearchThread.Destroy;
begin
  FExtensions.Free;  
  // Execute is still active at this point

  FIgnorePaths.Free; 
  // and still active here

  inherited;      
  // this calls Terminate and WaitFor, and that brings matters to a close, 
  // but not before the thread has opportunity to access the objects which
  // you just destroyed
end;
```

You'll need to redesign things to make sure that the thread does not use any objects after they have been destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, what I didn't know is that highest level `.Destroy()` is actually called BEFORE thread exits from `.Execute()`.

Comment: You can throw in calls to Terminate and WaitFor at the top of your DTOR